# Valgrind Error - Split of a String C

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have this program that reads a string and splits it in three parts. The first part is opcode, the second is data and the third is key.

Example of use:

```
put this is stackoverflow

opcode: put 
data: this is
key: stackoverflow
```

Code Main:

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv){
          char command[MAX_MSG];
          fgets(command, sizeof(command), stdin);
          command[strcspn (command, "\n")] = '\0';
          char *aux_command = strdup(command);
          char *opcode = strtok(command, " ");          
          int success = 0;
          char *key ;
          char *data;
          if(strcmp(opcode, "put") == 0){
             key = getKey(strdup(aux_command), opcode);
             if(key == NULL){
                   printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
                   success = -1;
             }

             else{
                   data = getData(aux_command, opcode, key);

             }
         }
         printf("opcode: %s\n",opcode);
         printf("data: %s\n",data);
         printf("key: %s\n",key);               
         free(aux_command);

}
```

My problem is when I run my program with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) it gives this result:

```
==2663==    by 0x4EBD971: strdup (strdup.c:42)
...
==2663==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 1 blocks
==2663==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2663==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2663==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2663==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2663== 
==2663== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

I don't know why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely NOT a good thing to use `memmove` here: you cannot use it when source and destination are overlapping, as it is the case here.

Comment: Why not just strtok the command string on spaces, use the first token as the opcode, last as the key, and join all the middle tokens with spaces to reconstruct your data?

Comment: @Bentoy13 memmove exists exactly for the sole purpose of dealing with overlapping memory: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove.

Comment: @Bentoy13:  That is incorrect about memmove and overlapping memory.  `memmove` is specifically defined to allow overlapping source/dest.  [See the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove).

Comment: My bad, I completely confused with memcpy. Thanks for having showing my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `free()` memory allocated by `strdup()` in line

```
key = getKey(strdup(aux_command), opcode);
```

The memory allocated by it is not getting freed and hence valgrind is showing it as memory lost.

Suggested code is:

```
...
      char *command =NULL; //declare variable
      char *key ;
      char *data;
      if(strcmp(opcode, "put") == 0){
         command = strdup(aux_command); //use variable to store new memory
         key = getKey(command, opcode);
         if(key == NULL){
               printf("Invalid number of arguments.\n");
               success = -1;
         }

         else{
               data = getData(aux_command, opcode, key);

         }
     }
     printf("opcode: %s\n",opcode);
     printf("data: %s\n",data);
     printf("key: %s\n",key);               
     free(aux_command);
     free(command); //free it when done
```

Comment: "Suggested code" would also benefit from checking if `strdup` returns NULL. ;)

Comment: Actually checks for NULL must be straight after strdup.

Comment: @Shahbaz, Agree, however the code is not complete code review, but suggestions on problem described.